# Can the answer be a photo taken of a written paper?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, answers

While answering the [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern) and some other puzzling, in case if I faced some difficulty to explain my answer by typing, can I write/draw the answer in the paper, taking that as a photo and add a picture to the answer is allowable?

Comment: Maybe you would want to change the title to - "_Can the answer be a photo taken **of** a written paper?_"

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Title corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Providing even a dim out-of-focus photo of unintelligibly handwritten work is infinitely better than including no explanation at all. Someone will appreciate _any explanation_, and it can always be improved, per the posted answers here, as time and other resources allow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is certainly allowable, but it's not an ideal solution.  If there is a picture or diagram you want to include as part of your answer, then definitely insert it as an image, but I would encourage you to type as much as possible of it as text.

Doing so helps the answer to be more searchable, and most of the time will be much easier to read.  It also lets you or someone else edit your answer if something needs to be changed or clarified.

For mathematical notation, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to construct just about any mathematical equation or construct.

If you don't feel capable of anything but posting a single image with the entire answer, I'd say that's still better than nothing, but far from ideal.

Comment: I'd like to add that, in my experience, if an answer requires a complicated mathematical formula or something and you don't know how to do it in MathJax, *somebody else does, and they will almost definitely edit it into your answer without any prompting*. So I think an image is fine, since it will probably be replaced with text eventually.

Answer (score 7):

You can of course click a picture of a handmade diagram to explain the answer well. But you need to **type** the plain text. You cannot post the picture of a plain text because:

- some users might not be able to understand your handwriting.
- the webpage will take time to load and it will create annoyance for other users.
- (half jokingly) save trees?

Comment: Save trees? I like this point :)

Answer (score 3):

I do agree with both the answers written.
I'd like to add one more point that while [adding a picture shows your homework/effort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28734/1766) on the question, you must make sure that others are able to understand your approach towards the given question(not that my handwriting is so bad). Thus adding lines of text explaining your idea makes it easier for fellow puzzlers to comprehend your thoughts :)

Comment: My hand-writing is some what good only, so no worries.